# How to use sed to extract text from a webpage

Tags: bash

Hey i'm using a combination of **sed** and **curl** to extract some text from the webpage [example.com](https://example.com)

here is my code

```
curl -s http://example.com | sed -n -e 's/.*<h1>\(.*\)<\/h1>.*<p>\(This.*\)<\/p>/\1 \n \2/p'
```

however, I don't get any output. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML/XML.

Comment: @Cyrus What should I use instead?

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although sed is generally not the right tool for extracting text from web pages it may be sufficent for simple tasks. sed is a line oriented tool. So each line will be handled separately.

If you really want to do it with sed, this will you give some output:

```
curl -s http://example.com | sed -n -e 's/.*<h1>\(.*\)<\/h1>/\1 \n/p' -e 's/<p>\(This.*\)/\1 \n/p'
```